# Simple bicubic image interpolation algorithm?

Tags: php, algorithm, delphi, interpolation

Most interpolation algorithm (Lanczos, Hermite, Bicubic) use very simple functions that calculate some values. But these values are then send through some very complicated functions which do some magic and voila- image is resized.
I want to understand this magic function (windowing function?) but most codes I find in Delphi, Pascal, PHP or simple C++ are already optimized or part of some huge libraries and use tons of subfunctions, classes and other things.
I just want to understand the basics.

For example, a function for "Nearest neighbor" in Delphi is:

```
function BoxFilter(Value: Single): Single;
begin
  if (Value > -0.5) and (Value <= 0.5) then
    Result := 1.0
  else
    Result := 0.0;
end;
```

How do I apply such a function to my 2D array of pixels (aka image)?

Comment: It is unclear what your actual question is.  E.g., in your first paragraph, you complain about "very complicated functions", but you do not describe them sufficiently to understand your complaint.

Comment: @comingstorm The functions I found are 20kB+ in size. That's quite a lot to analyze and understand the basics. So I wanted a simple explanation how to use filter function like the one I wrote above.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You first need to implement resize function. Basically resizing an image is repeatedly sampling the image for its data that corresponds to new image's pixels. Say, you resize a 101x101 image to 160*67. Then, a pixel at (0,0) of target image corresponds to sampling at (0.0,0.0) from source, this equals to the pixel at (0,0). But, a pixel at say (34,12) corresponds to `(34*100/159,12*100/66)` == `(21.38,18.18)` position in the source, for which you have to sample. The function you speak of returns a portion of selected pixel's value in the result, with value supplied equal to what's requested of sampling minus this pixel's corresponding coordinate. Say, a pixel at (4,3) will have a 0 part, because the function is applied multiplicatively for this pixel with values (21.38-4) and (18.18-3), both times returning a 0. The pixel at (21,18) will take 1 part (100% of its value will be added to the result), because both calls will be made with value within `-0.5 - 0.5` interval.

For you to correctly sample a color from your image at uneven coordinates, you take a function of these, then round the sampling values to detect the central pixel, then you apply the function to it and 8 surrounding pixels, receiving 9 values of participation. You then sum pixels' colors with participation as weights, combine them into one pixel value and return it as your sampling result.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you very much! With your explanation I managed to write a resampler which can do Hermite and Nearest Neighbor resampling! And the code is about 15 lines long (while the sources I found on the web are like 20kB in size with various optimizations and stuff- really hard to understand the basics).